# Load data from multiple lines with condition controller sqlldr

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

I have a csv file containing data as described below :

```
 - Data1|data2|data3....
 - Data4|data5|data6....
 - Ctr|1|2
 - Lst|1|30
 - Lst|1|40
 - Lst|1|50
 - Data7|data8....
 - Ctr|2|3
 - Lst|2|60
 - Lst|2|70
```

I have a table controle ( data_type varchar,
Id_control varchar,
Type_liste varchar,
Id_subcontrol varchar)

I am using sql loader to fill the table, the result I expect is :

```
 - data_type | Id_control|Type_liste| Id_subcontrol
 - Ctrl      | 1         |  NULL    | 2
 - Lst       | 1         |  30      | NULL
 - Lst       | 1         |  40      | NULL
 - Lst       | 1         |  50      | NULL
 - Ctr       | 2         | NULL     | 3
 - Lst       | 2         |  60      | NULL
 - Lst       | 2         |  70      | NULL
```

I've tried this but the second part return 0 rows loaded

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE controle 
WHEN (1:4) = 'Ctrl|' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(   
    Data_type                    CHAR, 
    Id_control                   CHAR,  
    Id_subcontrol                CHAR
    
)
INTO TABLE controle 
WHEN (1:3) = 'Lst'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(   
     Data_type                     CHAR,
     Id_control                    CHAR,
     type_list                     CHAR 
)
```

any idea please ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the docs say](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-7C0925AD-7156-4C30-BF19-3C3D3628A7DE):

> A key point when using multiple INTO TABLE clauses is that *field
> scanning continues* from where it left off when a new INTO TABLE clause
> is processed. The remainder of this section details important ways to
> make use of that behavior. It also describes alternative ways of using
> fixed field locations or the POSITION parameter.

So when processing the Lst condition, it's continuing to look for columns *on the current row*.

You can reset this by defining the first field with `position` to reset to the start of the line:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
TRUNCATE 
INTO TABLE controle 
WHEN Data_type = 'Ctr' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(   
    Data_type     CHAR, 
    Id_control    CHAR,  
    Id_subcontrol CHAR
    
)
INTO TABLE controle 
WHEN Data_type = 'Lst'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(   
     Data_type   POSITION(1:3) CHAR,
     Id_control  CHAR,
     type_list   CHAR 
)
BEGINDATA
Data1|data2|data3
Data4|data5|data6
Ctr|1|2
Lst|1|30
Lst|1|40
Lst|1|50
Data7|data8|data9
Ctr|2|3
Lst|2|60
Lst|2|70
```